# handle push notification (FCM) while app is in background / kill - Android

Tags: firebase, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, deep-linking

**What I want:** I want to send notification from **Firebase Console**. When app is in background/kill and when user taps on **Push Notification** it can go to particular activity. Let's call it **Current Offers Activity**. Same thing should happen while app will be in foreground.

**What I understood:** From **firebase docs**, when app is in foreground, push notifications sent from **Firebase Console** will be received in `onMessageReceived` method of `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class. But when app is in background/kill, the `onMessageReceived` method of `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class won't get called.

**What I want:** When app is in background/kill & user taps on push notification, I want to redirect user to particular activity (**Current Offers Activity**).

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/37845174#37845174) but I did not get the solution.

My code is like below.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private final String TAG = "mk";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.e(TAG, "Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private final String TAG = "mk";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.e(TAG, "MyFirebaseInstanceIDService Token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

**ActivityOne.java**

```
    public class ActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = "mk";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
                Log.e(TAG, key + " : " + extras.get(key));
            }
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Token: " + refreshedToken);

        //sendNotificationToPatner();
    }

    private void sendNotificationToPatner() {

        Log.e(TAG, "in sendNotificationToPatner: ");

        SendNotificationModel sendNotificationModel = new SendNotificationModel("check", "i miss you");

        RequestNotificaton requestNotificaton = new RequestNotificaton();
        requestNotificaton.setSendNotificationModel(sendNotificationModel);

        requestNotificaton.setToken("cJ-y3b3mnYk:APA91bEYTp1LtfpMHp-wdvKkq1_dVYF4DXl1SHWIaw0guwPSoTyFtbcJjPPB6GhP0FuRd9ybJ--BM6W3aFB-2-3KpVOBDITX91QV4kH1lAgxsIxHcfaj5FQLOIZ0t_HDC2bd8hqJrH-F4x_wuunJfYzanAagm4xcaA");

        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = apiService.sendChatNotification(requestNotificaton);

        responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "in onResponse");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "in onFailure");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check exact behavior of DATA and Pure Notification from FCM 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive according to app states.

Comment: Let me check, Although I already checked. May be something I might missed. If you can point out here in comment something which I missed, It would be better for other developers as well.@Rakesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. If you are sending push notification from firebase console & your app is in background or killed then **MyFirebaseMessagingService** won't get called. **(This is not mentioned in firebase documentation)**
2. If you are sending push notification from firebase console & your app is in foreground then **MyFirebaseMessagingService** will get called.
3. If you are sending push notification from your server(I mean back-end i.e a website or some web based dashboard) & your app is in background or kill or in foreground then **MyFirebaseMessagingService** will get called.

Comment: i am doing point 3 but i am not getting callback in MyFirebaseMessagingService can you please help me what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 5):

Well, I landed here looking for a solution to a different question but I can answer your question half-way.

If you are sending notification with data payload, then you can check the intent for specific extras. For example if in your console (firebase) you have a key ('custom_message') with some value ("This is my message") as shown in image below

[image]

You can listen to Intent's extras in the your launch activity which can be a splashscreen or mainactivity.

```
 Intent intent = getIntent(); 
    if (intent.getStringExtras("custom_message") != null) {
      //go to specific activity when notification is opened
    }
   else{
     //open open default launch activity 
    }
```

Now, earlier I said I will half-answer your question. Why? This is because I do not know how you would achieve that when the notification has no data payload. Hoping this helps someone.

@Maulik Dodia info is also very useful. Appreciated