# Not Receiving "custom push Notification" when app is in background in android devices on Oreo and above devices

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working chat application. I want to show custom push Notification when message receives, when app is open and closed (not destroyed or killed) notification are received, below code is working fine, but when app is killed or destroyed from background custom push notification is not received in oreo and above

Here is code I Used

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    try {
       context = getApplicationContext();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
       if ("message".equals(data.get("pushNotificationAction"))){
        System.out.println("message");


        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                0, intent, 0);
        String mediatype = data.get("mediaType");
        String mesageType= data.get("messageType");     

            String channel_id = createNotificationChannel(getApplicationContext());
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),channel_id)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.kisan_smoll_logo1)
                    .setCustomBigContentView(contentViewBig)
                    .setCustomContentView(contentViewBig)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(data.get("messageText"))
                    .setWhen(when)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);


            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

      }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Sending JSON from server is below:

```
     {
  "message":{
   "to": "FCMID", 
"data" : {
     "body" : "This is a Message!",
     "title" : "Notifiation Message"
 "mediaType":"IMAGE",
 "messageType":"chat",
      }
  }
}
```

By sending **data** from server custom Fcm push notification is received in android when app is open, but when app is swipe from recent notifications are not received

Comment: onMessageReceived Add logs for remoteMessagedata.getNotification().getBody() and check app open and close logs for same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handle push notification (FCM) while app is in background / kill - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177628/handle-push-notification-fcm-while-app-is-in-background-kill-android)

Comment: @GaneshPokale when app is open log , i can see the log but when app is close(distroyed) not able to see logs

Comment: @omel i am asking about custom Notification not from firebase console, which is not received  oreo and above devices in backgroud or when app is killed, this not duplicate

Comment: Add this logs for remoteMessagedata.getNotification().getBody() at  before  Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

Comment: As you asked i have added  log  like bellow, when app is open, i can see the log but when app is close(destroyed) not able to see logs                                             
mLogger.log("onMessageReceived" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();